# Hidding rows in excel due to change in a particular cell of another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

In a particular cell of sheet 1 we type No then Particular rows of sheet 2 shall hide and if we type yes they should be unhide. This code should be for n number of cells and every cell have some fixed no of rows which hide. The rows are different nor over lap and nor in any particular pattern. and the yes and no can be according to the requirement for different projects as its list of items in sheet1 and details of them in sheet 2

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Sheets("Sheet3").Rows("70:111").EntireRow.Hidden = False

If Target.Address = ("$L$3") And Target.Value = "No" Then

  Sheets("Sheet3").Rows("70:111").EntireRow.Hidden = True
  
End If

End Sub
```

i have tried this for individual cell but it didnt work it means it worked for one cell but when it comes to multiple its not working ...

Comment: Your code works for me. Please note that `... = "No"` is case sensitive. Also please elaborate on "*didnt work*"? Does the code actually run when you change cell L3? Do you get an error? Is the code saved in the correct sheet module?

Comment: You also need to unhide the rows in an `Else` clause. Otherwise, the rows will be unhidden every time any cell (other than L3) is changed. You should test **if cell is target** then **if value = yes** -> hide **else** unhide.

Comment: it works for only one cell considered when it comes to multiple cells rows becomes unhidden when adding code for another cell and putting no in different boxes

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research i found the answer myself by trial and error method in which multiple rows can be hidden according to the need and accordint to the value in the cell

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

 Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim entireRange As Range
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set ws3 = wb.Sheets("Sheet3")

' Unhide Rows
Sheets("Sheet3").Rows("70:393").EntireRow.Hidden = False

' Case 1
 Select Case Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("L3").Value
 
    Case "No"
         Sheets("Sheet3").Range("70:135").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Case "Yes"
          Sheets("Sheet3").Range("70:135").EntireRow.Hidden = False
          
    End Select
    
  ' Case 2
  Select Case Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("L4").Value

   Case "No"
      Sheets("Sheet3").Range("197:218").EntireRow.Hidden = True
   Case "Yes"
     Sheets("Sheet3").Range("197:218").EntireRow.Hidden = False
          
    End Select
    
' Case 3
  Select Case Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("L5").Value

   Case "No"
       Sheets("Sheet3").Range("220:249").EntireRow.Hidden = True
   Case "Yes"
        Sheets("Sheet3").Range("220:249").EntireRow.Hidden = False
          
    End Select
    
'Case 4

Select Case Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("L6").Value

   Case "No"
     Sheets("Sheet3").Range("251:276").EntireRow.Hidden = True
   Case "Yes"
       Sheets("Sheet3").Range("251:276").EntireRow.Hidden = False
          
    End Select
    
 ' Case 5
 
 Select Case Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("L7").Value

   Case "No" 
     Sheets("Sheet3").Range("278:367").EntireRow.Hidden = True
   Case "Yes"
       Sheets("Sheet3").Range("278:367").EntireRow.Hidden = False
          
    End Select
    
 ' Case 6
 
 Select Case Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("L8").Value

   Case "No"
      Sheets("Sheet3").Range("370:393").EntireRow.Hidden = True
   Case "Yes"
         Sheets("Sheet3").Range("370:393").EntireRow.Hidden = False
          
    End Select
    
    End Sub
```

This code worked for multiple cells i have coded it according to my need

**Update By Supersymmetry:**

Just to slightly optimise your code and make it more concise:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("L3:L8")) Is Nothing Then
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")
      .Range("070:135").EntireRow.Hidden = Me.Range("L3") = "No"
      .Range("197:218").EntireRow.Hidden = Me.Range("L4") = "No"
      .Range("220:249").EntireRow.Hidden = Me.Range("L5") = "No"
      .Range("251:276").EntireRow.Hidden = Me.Range("L6") = "No"
      .Range("278:367").EntireRow.Hidden = Me.Range("L7") = "No"
      .Range("370:393").EntireRow.Hidden = Me.Range("L8") = "No"
    End With
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Let me know if you want an explanation of my update to your code.

Comment: actually the above code didn't worked when i used it i used it before posting the question but when i put no in many blocks thne only one is hidden thus i actually asked the question